# How to have session time logout for the entire website?

Tags: php

I wish to build an eCommerce website with session time logout account, I know about session_start(), session_destroy(), and time().

I use this code at my login.php, this code executed once submitted the login form:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
header("location:logined.php");
```

here is the code at logined.php :

```
<?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) 
      {
        if((time() - $_SESSION['time']) > 90 )
        {
          header('location:logout.php');
        }
        else
        {
          $_SESSION['time'] = time();
          echo"<div class='register-header d-flex flex-column py-5'>";
          echo"<h1 align='center'>SESSION TIME</h1>";
          echo"<h1 align='center'>".$_SESSION['time']."</h1>";
          echo"</div>";
        }
      }
      ?>
```

So with these, I was able to create a session time logout but it is only for the logined.php, I just use this code from tutorial video at youtube... how do I create these session time logout for the entire website?

Comment: what about calling `session_start()` in each page

Comment: What else did you try? Where are you stuck? If you really want to write a eCommerce website, you will probably have more common stuff that should be shared between pages? Also, please don't start your project with such chaotic code - don't mix HTML markup and logic, don't forget to use `exit`  after sending a `Location` header

Answer (score 1):

*You need to create a file session.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    if ((time() - $_SESSION['time']) > 90) {
        header('location:logout.php');
    }
}else{
    header('location:logout.php');
}
```

*now in every *.php where you wants to maintain this session check please include this file on the beginning of the each file like
profile.php*

```
<?php
require_once("session.php");

// YOUR CODE HERE
```